# .NET Core - Docker build can't find SDK version in global.json

Tags: docker, .net-core

I have a .NET (Core) 5.0 solution with a global.json because I want to keep a specific SDK version:

```
{
    "sdk": {
        "version": "5.0.302"
    }
}
```

5.0.302 is installed on my machine, and the solution opens in Visual Studio (for Mac) and builds just fine,  but when I try to build with Docker from the command line I get:

```
A compatible installed .NET SDK for global.json version [5.0.302] from [/src/global.json] was not found.
```

The image used in my Dockerfile is:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
```

I don't think I understand the global.json docs. I tried changing the version in global to 5.0.0 and adding `rollforward: latestFeature`. Now Docker will build, but Visual Studio won't build when I open the project:

```
.NET Core 5.0.0 SDK is required to build this application, and is not installed.
```

I expected VS to use the installed 5.0.302 in this case, but it doesn't.

Comment: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 is version 5.0.400 at the moment and is probably going to change to something newer at some point. As far as I can see, a docker image with 5.0.302 isn't available anymore on Microsoft's registry. The full list of tags is here: https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-sdk?tab=description

Comment: Thanks. I thought that 5.0.0 in global with rollforward would allow Docker to use 5.0.400 (or whatever is the latest), and VS would use my installed 5.0.302.

Answer (score 0):

While a 5.0.302 SDK isn't listed in the Microsoft registry, it was available when I tried to pull it.

Try changing your Dockerfile to

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0.302 AS build
```

I don't know how often Microsoft clean their registry, but you should probably be prepared for the image to disappear at some point.

If you can, I'd advise you to not rely on a specific version of the SDK.

Comment: Thanks very much. I think not using global.json is the way to go. I added it a while ago when I started getting failures using preview versions of VS and switching back.